# php can't connect to database after using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I'm trying to delete a comment on the website and also from database, but it just works find on web site. After I click delete button, the comment is gone, but nothing changed in my database. After I refresh the page, the comments I deleted appear again.
So I think, somehow, ajax makes php disconnect to MySQL database anymore.

jquery:

```
$(".delete").each(function (index4) {
    $(this).on("click",function (event) {
        $(this).parent().parent().load("../public/form/delete_comments.php", {index4:index4}, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    })
```

php:

```
<?php
require_once "../../private/initialize.php";
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$thread_clicked = isset($_POST['index4'])?$_POST['index4']:'';

$req_user = "SELECT * FROM log_in WHERE id='" .$id. "'";
$result_user = mysqli_query($db,$req_user);
$subject_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user);

$req = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE user=`" .$subject_user['account']. "` AND c_id=`" .$thread_clicked. "`";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$req);
```

UPDATE: i changed ajax to :`$(this).parent().parent().load("/yyqGS/public/form/delete_comments.php",{index4:index4});`

but still doesn't do any change to database.

UPDATE:

```
  <?php
require_once "../../private/initialize.php";
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$thread_clicked = isset($_POST['index4'])?$_POST['index4']:'';
$thread_clicked = $thread_clicked +1;
$req_user = "SELECT * FROM log_in WHERE id='.$id.'";
$result_user = mysqli_query($db,$req_user);
$subject_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user);


$req = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE user='" .$subject_user['account']. "' AND c_id='" .$thread_clicked. "'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$req);

if ( !$req ) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli_error($db));
}
else{
    echo $result;
}
```

and i got 1 everytime i delete a comment, but database still doesn't change!

Magic just happened! I don't even know what have I done (I fixed quotation marks problem), but it just works know!

```
    <?php
require_once "../../private/initialize.php";
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$thread_clicked = isset($_POST['index4'])?$_POST['index4']:'';
$thread_clicked = $thread_clicked +1;

$req_user = "SELECT * FROM log_in WHERE id='".$id."'";
$result_user = mysqli_query($db,$req_user);
$subject_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user);

$req = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE user='" .$subject_user['account']. "' AND c_id='" .$thread_clicked. "'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$req);



if ( !$req ) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli_error($db));
}
else{
    echo $req;
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your ajax url in the network does it hit correct ?

Comment: @user6606700 it should be, since php file can get index4 value.

Comment: this code is vulnerable to sql injection and the two sql queries could be combined. Use prepared statements!!

Comment: "it should be" means you did not check. Open the developer console tab and see where your ajax call is been made. If it fails try to put absolute path in your ajax load function.

Comment: @pr1nc3 i just checked, the url is correct.

Comment: So in the developer console in your browser what is the error php gives? Is ajax call even happen? In the network tab you can see this info.

Comment: @pr1nc3 there are no errors, every thing looks just fine. php did delete the comment on website, but nothing happened in database. after refresh the page, the comment appear again.

Comment: I have posted an answer. try it and let me know to edit my post with further explanation of fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once "../../private/initialize.php";
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$thread_clicked = isset($_POST['index4'])?$_POST['index4']:'';

$req_user = "SELECT * FROM log_in WHERE id='$id'";
$result_user = mysqli_query($db,$req_user);
$subject_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user);

$req = $result = mysqli_query($db,$req);

$req = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE user='"$subject_user['account']"' AND c_id='"$thread_clicked"'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$req);
```

Try this code for your php. If it works fine i will edit with explanation.

Comment: i tried your code, still the same, it only delete comment on website, but doesn't connect to database.

Comment: It deletes in the website because your javascript takes care of this, front end has nothing to do with php. Made one more small change in the code give it another try. If it still does nothing try put a break-point somewhere in the code like an `echo "I am here";` In the developer tab of the ajax call , in the response tab on the right where you see the output of the php you should see it. Also try set in require_once absolute path of  db connection file.

Comment: alright, my bad. my js file doesn't connect to my php file.

Comment: In your load function give the absolute path then of your php file.

Comment: i tried, but still nothing. i also tried to print out what the $result is. (if it success, should print out 1 -- true ) , and i got "1" after i delete a comment. but database still doesn't change!

Comment: Did you use the query i provide you in my code or the query you had in your code?

Comment: alright, it works now.. i think there is just some stupid problems with my code. since i print out $req, i just realized $subject['account'] was not correct, and there was some quotation marks problems. after i fixed them, it just works now. lol, i feel so stupid now.

Comment: That was what i fixed in my query  also. the quotes were wrong. That's why i told you to use my query and not the one you had on your question. Accept one of the two answers that you think fits most in your question so this thread has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the wrong quotes in your delete statement - your using back ticks which is used to identify fields, not surround values.

```
$req = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE user=`" .$subject_user['account']. "` AND c_id=`" .$thread_clicked. "`";
```

should be

```
$req = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE user='" .$subject_user['account']. "' AND c_id='" .$thread_clicked. "'";
```

with single quotes rather than backticks.

Edit: It's also useful to check the return values from queries...

```
if ( !$result ) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli_error($db));
}
```

Should let you know if there are any problems with the delete.

Comment: I've added some code to output an error(if one occurs)

Comment: since this is my first time using ajax, i'm not totally understand how it works, but after i delete a comment, the page didn't automatically turn to delete_comments.php, which is this php file. In stead, it stayed at the same page I delete comments. So the result wouldn't show up.

Comment: I use Chrome and if you go to Inspect, you can go to the Network pane which shows you the Ajax calls being made, click on the request being made and it should show you any return values from the page.  Not sure how other browsers do this, but may help.

Comment: ok i think i found the problem, my jquery doesn't connect to my php file.

Comment: It's not always easy to find out where in the chain the problem is, but at least you've found where part of the problem is.

Comment: so sad that was not the problem, lol. so i try to print out what the $result is. (if it success, should print out 1 -- true ) , and i got "1" after i delete a comment. but database still doesn't change!

Comment: OK - try `echo $req;` check the SQL statement it's running.  Try running this in phpmyadmin and see if it updates what your expecting.

Comment: OMG, after i echo $req; i just realized there were some problem with my $subject['account']. And also some quotation mark problem. after fixed them, everting works fine now. I feel like i just asked a stupid question. but thank you very much!

Comment: Part of learning is asking stupid questions.  Main thing is you've learned a bit more about developing.  Debugging Ajax can be a pain, so this should mean you have some ideas on how to do this in the future.  Enjoy :)